# Vuetify - how to create a nested multi-select box

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a multi-select box with Vuetify that allows the user to select the `header` and by selecting the `header` they would select everything that is child to that.

[Here is an example:](https://zon-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/) if you click on the "choose your countries" you'll see `Europe` BUT its just a title for now. I'd like to make that another checkbox that if selected would then choose all the countries under Europe.

Here is my code so far on the multi-select

```
<v-select
  label="Choose your Countries"
  :items="countries"
  v-model="country_selects"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="value"
  multiple
  chips
  hint="What are the target regions"
  persistent-hint
  autocomplete
></v-select>
```

And then the data in my `script` section

```
data: function () {
return {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  select: null,
  items: [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4'
  ],
  country_selects: [],
  countries: [
    {header: "Europe"},
    {name: "Afghanistan", value: "AF"},
    {name: "Second", value: "DF"},
    {header: "Second"},
    {name: "Charlotte", value: "AF"},
    {name: "North Carolina", value: "DF"},       
    ],
```

So far I found the `header` key but I need to turn it into a checkbox. Any ideas?